# Emacs shortcut to go to a specific line in a file

Tags: emacs, line-numbers

I'm learning Emacs after over two years of using Notepad++ as my default editor. I'm still hung up on a few things, but I find myself kind of enjoying working with it.

My question is simple: in Notepad++, when I wanted to go to a specific line of my file, I used <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>. Emacs, for some perplexing reason, requires me to do <kbd>M-x goto-line [enter] $linenumber [enter]</kbd>.

I can't believe there isn't a shortcut for that. I must be googling wrong, surely?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

<kbd>M-g g</kbd> or <kbd>M-g M-g</kbd> are the default bindings for `goto-line`.

And, the easiest way to find this is either <kbd>M-x where-is RET goto-line RET</kbd> which will list the bindings for the command `goto-line`, or you can type <kbd>C-h b</kbd> which lists all the bindings for the current buffer (and then you can peruse the bindings to see if `goto-line` is there, or to discover other useful commands & bindings.

Comment: Never feel stupid, while learning emacs. There are miles/years to go on this journey.

Answer (score 8):

[Trey Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14712037) is correct, but another useful thing to know in emacs is how to discover this sort of thing on your own. In your case, you know the name of the command -- `goto-line`. If you type 'C-h w' (Control+h and then w), Emacs will as you "Where is command: ". Type goto-line and hit enter, and it will tell you what keystrokes (if any) are bound to that command.

There are a bunch more similar features. 'C-h k' does the inverse -- asks you for a keystroke and then tells you the command it runs; 'C-h b' shows all current keybindings; 'C-h a' will search for a string, so you might type 'C-h a goto' to search for commands with "goto" in the name; 'C-h v' describes variables; 'C-h f' describes functions; etc.

Comment: and if you activate suggest-key-bindings, you will see a message like "You can run the command `goto-line' with M-g" _automatically_.

To do that (setq suggest-key-bindings 't)

Comment: You can also type `C-h ?` to see a list of the help commands, this will list all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're an emacs newbie, [this webpage](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abuf) gives a detailed explanation on how to find specific line numbers.

For me (on a mac), it was `M-x goto-line` (where I get the "M" meta key by pressing and immediately releasing the escape button).

Answer (score 0):

try `M-<`, then `C-u n C-n`, goes to (n+1)<sup>th</sup> line.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://github.com/davep/goto-line-faster.el

Which reduces <kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>M-g</kbd> `<number>` to simply <kbd>M-g</kbd> `<number>` *without* messing with any other uses of <kbd>M-g</kbd> as a prefix binding.

Being a command that I use fairly frequently, I've found this small optimisation highly agreeable.